# Do I need to add source sets in build.gradle for release/debug java source folders?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, source-sets

I added a new Java source folder `release` (app/src/release/java) for our release buildType. For this Android Studio automatically added this line to my app/build.gradle:

```
 sourceSets { release { java.srcDirs = ['src/release/java', 'src/release/java/'] } }
```

We already had some code in the `debug` folder (app/src/debug/java) for our debug buildType. And there is no entry in the app/build.gradle file for debug source set.

And our release and debug builds are working as expected with and without the sourceSet entry.

So, is it that gradle looks for the source for build type `x` in `app/src/x/java` by default while building.

If yes, why did Android-Studio added the sourceSet line in build.gradle for me?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#sourcesets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so Android Studio had added sourceSet to build.gradle cause I had marked 'Change Folder Location' while adding folder 'release' for buildType 'release'.

[image: img1]

And by default Gradle does look for the source for build type `x` in `app/src/x/java`.

For example, for debug build type, there's no sourceSet entry in build.gradle. And on `./gradlew sourceSets` it gives:

[image: img2]

So there's no need to add sourceSet to build.gradle if you are not using custom folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can create different "sourceSets" which basically just help you to organize code between different variants of your application. Every sourceSet except for the "main" set is optional.

You can find more in depth information about this topic on the [android developer hub](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html#sourcesets).